# ExpressJs: Browser not sending cookies set for another domain set by api server

Tags: express, cookies

I have an admin dashboard react app that's running on `admin.localhost.com:3000`. I have an api server that's running on `www.localhost.com:1337`, and we have one react app for all clients, but each client uses it on a subdomain, for example, `abc.localhost.com:4200`, `bcd.localhost.com:4200`.

So from my admin dashboard I'm trying to log into `abc` as a client. The api server, when requested, verifies the admin, sets the cookie in the response for `abc.localhost.com:4200` and responds with link for the client `https://abc.localhost.com/home`. The browser code passes the link to `window.open()`.

However, if I check the browser tab for `https:abc.localhost.com:4200`, I don't see the cookie, so obviously the authentication fails.

```
res.cookie('token', token, {
        secure: true,
        domain: `abc.localhost.com:4200`,
        sameSite: 'Lax',
        maxAge: moment()
          .add(10, 'minutes')
          .valueOf(),
      })
```

`withCredentials` is enabled for the client side agent, and the api server is configured accordingly.

Comment: Add (.) dot before the domain. For example: use `.localhost.com:4200` instead. This will allow cookies across all subdomains

Answer (score -1):

It can't be done, server running on `www.localhost.com:1337` can't set cookies for `abc.localhost.com:4200`. Allowing that would be apocalyptic.